# Textbox only clickable on "first row"

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox

I have a textbox and which is higher then a "normal" textbox. I am only able to enter text if I click on the "first row" of the textbox. How can I make it possible to click on any part of the textbox and be able to get the cursor shown because this is pretty anoying if you have a 5 line textbox and have to click on the first line to enter some text

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,15,0">
      <TextBlock x:Name="lblObjective" Text="Objective" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
      <TextBox x:Name="Objective"  Text="{Binding ObjectiveText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="120" Width="500"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Edit:

This is the template that affects all textboxes in my application. Can anyone say what I need to add to be able to click anywhere on the textbox and still get the caret instead of having to click on the first line

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusRectangle" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusRectangle" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusInnerRectangle"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                <Storyboard/>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Base" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="1" Fill="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusRectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverBorderBrush}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusInnerRectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" Margin="1" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverInnerBorderBrush}" />
                    <Grid Margin="0,1,0,0">
                        <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="{StaticResource ReadOnlyBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Grid >
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Margin="4,0,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Stroke="{StaticResource ControlsDisabledBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Fill="{StaticResource ControlsDisabledBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlsValidationBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToolTip.Triggers>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                            <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="{StaticResource ValidationBrush5}" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteColorBrush}" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

If I remove the whole template everything works fine (i.e. wherever I click on the textbox I get a carret) but then the rest is also lost. So I am missing something any ideas?

Edit 2:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Margin="4,0,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

was the root of the problem... Instead of having `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` it was set to top and therefor only one line was clickable...

Comment: Is the intent to make it multi-line? Setting `AcceptsReturn="True"` might help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are seeing but I find that in such a textbox clicking anywhere in the textbox gives it the input focus so I can start editing (regardless BTW of the state of `AcceptsReturn` although you should have that turned on).

However if the place you click in the box is beyond the end of the current string value the caret is placed at the end of the content not at the place you clicked.  This is common text box behaviour, the text box in stackoverflow where I'm typing this has the same behaviour.

If you want to be able to start typing anywhere in the TexBox then you will need to detect the text position of the mousedown and inject the appropriate amount of whitespace.  Not a trivial matter.

Comment: The problem was an implicit style which affected the textbox. I was only able to type in something if I click on the first line otherwise nothing happened. Now if I click somewhere the caret moves to the last letter.